# Getting event attending_count on venue-id/events on Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the attending_count on facebook graph API. I know that going throug `/event-id?fields=attending_count` I will have this info available but when trying this inside the venue `/venue-id/events?fields=attending_count` this is not being displayed.

Here is what i'm trying:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/217733628398158/events?fields=id,cover,name,venue,description,ticket_uri,start_time,attending_count&access_token=....
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `attending_count` field on the Event object, but there is an `attending` edge:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/event#readfields
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/event/attending#read

Why are you trying to get the `attending_count` on the Venue's Page ID? That doesn't make much sense.

You can use the `summary` to get the absolute count of attendees like this

```
/217733628398158/events?fields=id,cover,name,venue,description,ticket_uri,start_time,attending.summary(true).limit(1)
```

To reduce the amount of data returned by the Graph API I added the `.limit(1)` which is only returning one attendee per event, but producing the summary count anyway. If you need the whole list, remove the `limit` parameter.

So, it returns

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "326299167565639", 
      "cover": {
        "cover_id": "839491946113340", 
        "source": "https://scontent-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/t31.0-8/s720x720/10547740_839491946113340_540194689313513221_o.jpg", 
        "offset_y": 28, 
        "offset_x": 0
      }, 
      "name": "Feeling This • Histórias de verão", 
      "venue": {
        "name": "Lima e Silva, 1037, Porto Alegre"
      }, 
      "description": "ARE YOU FEELING THIS?\nÉ a nostalgia da estação quente que tá batendo!\n\nFaça aqui a sua história de verão.\nThese are the best days of our lives!\n\n-\n\nIngressos:\nR$15 com Feeling Cup!*\nR$20 na lista* <http://goo.gl/1I9vV8>\nR$25 na hora\n\n* Lista encerra às 20h do dia da festa. \n* Válido para entrada até 00h\n\n\nQuer comemorar seu aniversário na FEELING THIS? Entre em contato através do e-mail cucko@cucko.com.br para saber das vantagens.", 
      "ticket_uri": "https://www.facebook.com/ajax/events/ticket.php?event_id=326299167565639&source=12&ext=1421830108&hash=ATX8w7CCSBVhKO6G", 
      "start_time": "2015-02-04T22:00:00-0200", 
      "attending": {
        "data": [
          {
            "name": "Foo Pretenders", 
            "rsvp_status": "attending", 
            "id": "1395261354109384"
          }
        ], 
        "paging": {
          "cursors": {
            "after": "TVRBd01EQTROelkxT1RnMk9UYzBPakUwTWpNd09UUTBNREE2TVRZMU1EZzBPRGsyT0RRNE5UZ3g=", 
            "before": "TVRBd01EQTROelkxT1RnMk9UYzBPakUwTWpNd09UUTBNREE2TVRZMU1EZzBPRGsyT0RRNE5UZ3g="
          }, 
          "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/326299167565639/attending?summary=true&limit=1&after=TVRBd01EQTROelkxT1RnMk9UYzBPakUwTWpNd09UUTBNREE2TVRZMU1EZzBPRGsyT0RRNE5UZ3g="
        }, 
        "summary": {
          "count": 634
        }
      }
    },
    ....
]
```

There are 634 people attending the specific event.

Comment: Thanks @Tobi! Just for understanfing, where this property come from? Is it something from Facebook API? Can you please point me some documentation about any other properties like this?

Comment: It's not really documented afaik, only for some edges like object comments and likes, see e.g. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/object/comments#readfields

Comment: You can even do `attending.limit(0).summary(true)` :)